Error of Could not reach host. Are you offline when converting html file into PDF
I am attempting to change an html file into PDF document. I tried multiple methods but none of them proved effective. The html documentwas saved stored on the U drive of my company's network.
For instance, when I am use pyhtml2pdf,  I consistently encounter the error displayed below.
https://pypi.org/project/pyhtml2pdf/
from pyhtml2pdf import converter
filepath_html='U:/Data/test.html'
path = os.path.abspath(filepath_html)
converter.convert(f'{path}', 'sample.pdf')


    714 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 715 httplib_response = self._make_request(
    716     conn,
    717     method,
    718     url,
    719     timeout=timeout_obj,
    720     body=body,
    721     headers=headers,
    722     chunked=chunked,
    723 )
    725 # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then
    726 # the response doesn't need to know about the connection. Otherwise
    727 # it will also try to release it and we'll have a double-release
    728 # mess.

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda_envs\dash3\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:404, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    403 try:
--> 404     self._validate_conn(conn)
    405 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    406     # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

File c:\ProgramData\anaconda_envs\dash3\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1060, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
...
---> 35     raise exceptions.ConnectionError(f"Could not reach host. Are you offline?")
     36 self.validate_response(resp)
     37 return resp

ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?



have you looked at the documentation? If you want to convert a local file, you have to use file:///path URL syntax.

Thanks Barmar, I just did like this converter.convert(f'file:///{path}', f'file:///{path_export}'), and I got same error

it seems more like a network issue, check if you can reach the directory for real, check for any firewall/proxy settings that may be blocking the connection.
Also, one message indicate an issue with ssl connection, so try to investigate that.
